# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Magento\Framework\Event\mb_strtolower() in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php-7, cli

when i run

cli commends I'm getting error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Magento\Framework\Event\mb_strtolower() in /home/project/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php:56
```

phpinfo.php

[image]

why this happening
how I can solve this??

Comment: Does this error occur in your local system or server? If so server is it shared or dedicated?

Comment: in my cpanel login no terminal and ssh

Comment: Is it shared hosting? If VPS do you have access to WHM

Comment: i have but no option for apache and ssh

Comment: In that case, you will have access to easy apache right, Please check there for the site if mbstring extension is enabled

Comment: what is mean by easy apache

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96647/discussion-between-raj-mohan-r-and-prabhakaran7).